# Why does my code not insert the data into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?php
 require 'connect.inc.php';

$food= $_POST['food'];
$cost= $_POST['cost'];

$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (eat, pay) VALUES ('$food','$cost')";

?> 

<form method = "POST" action = "index.php">
    Food: <input type = "text" name = "food">
            <br/>
    Cost: <input type = "text" name = "cost">
            <br/>
            <input type = "submit" value = "order">
</form>
```

Why does my code not work? index.php is fine, it connects well, but no output is shown in my database when I run this code.

Comment: where did you run the query?

Comment: Because assigning query text to a variable doesn't mean that query will be executed.

Comment: execute mysqli_query()

Comment: *"It connects well"* - Being what, mysql_? mysqli_? PDO? Other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be new at databases, seeing your other questions and this being the only one related to doing db work.

This line never gets executed:

```
$sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO test (eat, pay) VALUES ('$food','$cost')";
```

We don't know which MySQL API you are using to connect with; if it's `mysql_`, or `mysqli_` or PDO, or other since you did not mention that in your question.

Depending on the API used, you need to run `mysql_query()`, or `mysqli_query()` or `query()/execute()` in PDO.

Consult the following links on how to do this:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php / http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php

Check for errors also using the same API you connected with, and seeing that you're more than likely running this code inside the same file, you need to use a conditional statement around your POST arrays to check if they're empty, and/or use an `isset()` on the submit button and giving it a "name" attribute.

I.e.: `<input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "order">`

with `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}`

Otherwise, you stand at getting errors thrown back.

If empty reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Note: Different MySQL APIs do not intermix, so you can't connect with `mysql_` and query with `mysqli_query()` or PDO, keep this in mind.

Another thing is to make sure that data going into the database doesn't contain characters that MySQL will complain about such as apostrophes.

Therefore you will need to escape that data. This is good for another reason, avoiding a possible SQL injection; you should use a prepared statement for it.

References:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

---

**Footnotes:**

If you are using the `mysql_` API to connect with, that API is deprecated and has been removed in PHP 7.0. If this is the case, then you will need to use either the `mysqli_` or PDO API.